# CSS Responsive table not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on responsive css for a table. I read a tutorial from this link http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/ (How to make responsive table on css). It worked on some sample page but in my `HTML` page I have some problem on re-sizing of window and the table does not respond correctly. Here's my HTML code:

```
    <style>
        /* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
        table
        {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        /* Zebra striping */
        tr:nth-of-type(odd)
        {
            background: #eee;
        }
        th
        {
            background: #333;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        td, th
        {
            padding: 6px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: left;
        }
        /* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
        @media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
        {
            /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
            table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr
            {
                display: block;
            }
            /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
            thead tr
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: -9999px;
                left: -9999px;
            }
            tr
            {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
            td
            {
                /* Behave  like a "row" */
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 50%;
            }
            td:before
            {
                /* Now like a table header */
                position: absolute; /* Top/left values mimic padding */
                top: 6px;
                left: 6px;
                width: 45%;
                padding-right: 10px;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            /*
    Label the data
    */
            td:nth-of-type(1):before
            {
                content: "First Name";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(2):before
            {
                content: "Last Name";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(3):before
            {
                content: "Job Title";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(4):before
            {
                content: "Favorite Color";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(5):before
            {
                content: "Wars of Trek?";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(6):before
            {
                content: "Porn Name";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(7):before
            {
                content: "Date of Birth";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(8):before
            {
                content: "Dream Vacation City";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(9):before
            {
                content: "GPA";
            }
            td:nth-of-type(10):before
            {
                content: "Arbitrary Data";
            }
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        First Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Last Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Job Title
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        James
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Matman
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Chief Sandwich Eater
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        The
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Tick
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Crimefighter Sorta
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It shows  the output on re-size window like the figure below:

[image]

and it worked well on js-fiddle like the figure below:

[image]

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9Yp/

What's wrong in my code? Can any one guide me, thanks!

Comment: What browser did you test your code on? I tested on Chrome and Firefox and IE it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define a `min-width` between your specified viewport. To the parent element `table` and the child `tr` if wanted / needed.

```
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  min-width: 320px; // this should do it
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

And.

```
tr { 
   min-width: 200px; // specify if additionally needed or wanted
}
```

What resolution are you optimizing for -- I see your `@media` is tablet but your shooting for smaller obviously -- you shouldn't need to go below `320px;` in most cases, so if you minimize below that it shouldn't matter.

Also, why not use nested `divs`?

Comment: It does, I've tested it; if your seeking something more specific please update your answer.

Comment: i find solution buddy check my answer :), thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

It's small mistake i don't specify top of html document type as html5

after it does work perfectly on existing code

`<!DOCTYPE html>`